# Response error from API Gateway HTTP endpoint to AWS Elasticsearch domain

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, aws-api-gateway, velocity, aws-elasticsearch

I have a post endpoint in API gateway with the HTTP request integration. It's not a proxy endpoint. The URL it's pointed at is the search URL for my AWS ElasticSearch domain. I'm taking the body of the post request and mapping it to a template to query the ES domain with.

Right now I'm getting this response back from ES: `{"Message":"User: anonymous is not authorized to perform: es:ESHttpPost"}`.

I don't have fine grained access control enabled on the ES Domain, and it's not in a VPC. My JSON access policy looks like this:

```
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": "*"
      },
      "Action": "es:ESHttp*",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:es:xx-xxxx-x:999999999999:domain/XXXXX/*",
      "Condition": {
        "IpAddress": {
          "aws:SourceIp": [
            "X.X.X.X/X",
            "X.X.X.X/X"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

With this policy, I'm able to reach out and query the domain directly and navigate to the Kibana dashboard while on the IP's I have in the allow list. However, I'm assuming the query request coming from my gateway endpoint has a different IP address as that's where I get the 403 response mentioned above.

I know I can find the origin IP address in the request in the `x-forwarded-for` header, but I don't think I'm able to add that as a condition to the ES access policy, I've tried a few other policy conditions as well, such as a StringLike for the principle ARN and looking for the method request ARN, but these don't work.
Ideally, I would like to just be able to override the sourceIP with the actual origin and not gateway's IP address, but I don't know if this is possible. I also know I could just use a lambda function here, but I would like to avoid needing a function here, to avoid having code / another service to maintain.

Basically, I'm hoping to be able to still allow anonymous user access when requests are coming from certain IP's, but I want to create and abstract certain frequently used queries with a few gateway endpoints. Is there a way I can add the API endpoint to the allow list, or do I have to enable fine-grained access control?

Comment: I learned that AWS shares out the IP ranges in a JSON list for each of its services. Adding the API_GATEWAY ranges to my list fixes the issue, but that's not exactly an ideal fix, I'll have to update the list periodically. I can automate that but I'm still hoping there's a better solution to this.